# Is what Russia is doing in Ukraine in violation of the Russian Constitution?

Tags: constitutional-law, laws-of-war, russia, ukraine

A lot of what Russia is doing in Ukraine appears to be in violation of international laws. As the ICC Chief Prosecutor Karim Khan said "Ukraine is a crime scene" ([Barrons](https://www.barrons.com/news/ukraine-is-a-crime-scene-icc-chief-prosecutor-01649849407)).

I'm wondering if it is also against Russia's domestic laws, esp the Constitution of the Russian Federation (RF or just "Russia" below).

English translation of the Constitution here: https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Russia

While I'm no law expert (certainly not in Russian constitutional law), a quick read brings up a few relevant areas:

- Article 17 "... rights and freedoms of humans and citizens" - it appears that the constitution gives equal rights to citizens and non-citizens. Do non-citizens in occupied territories have those rights, or does this only cover the territory of Russia?
- Article 20 "Everyone shall have the right to life" - seems straightforward, this would prohibit killing civilians. A very literal reading would seem to prohibit any lethal warfare entirely (in the same way as the death penalty is prohibited). How is killing of combatants allowed under this?
- Article 21 "No one shall be subject to torture", 22 "Arrest, detention ... shall be allowed only by court decision", Article 25 "No one shall have the right to enter a home against the will of those living there" and so on - what has been reported from Bucha, Borodianka etc would seem to be an obvious and massive violation of all of these.
- Article 26 "Everyone shall have the right to determine and indicate his nationality" - forced deportations of civilians from Ukraine to RF, and forcibly issuing them RF passports, would seem to be in violation of this. (sources: [CNN](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/world/2022/04/07/ukraine-forced-deportations-to-russia-pkg-polglase-intl-ldn-vpx.cnn) [MSN](https://www.msn.com/en-gb/news/world/russia-war-crimes-investigators-reveal-e2-80-98numerous-and-consistent-e2-80-99-reports-of-forced-ukrainian-deportations/ar-AAWbpwl))
- Article 15 "The universally-recognised norms of international law and international treaties and agreements of the Russian Federation shall be a component part of its legal system. If an international treaty or agreement of the Russian Federation establishes other rules than those envisaged by law, the rules of the international agreement shall be applied. " - this would imply that for example the various parts of the Geneva convention ratified by Russia are binding, and even override domestic laws.

The constitution doesn't say much about war, how and for what purposes war can be declared, and what the role and obligations of the armed forces is.

**Is there anything in the constitution which would prohibit a war of aggression?** (eg to capture territory)

and

**Is there anything which would prohibit carrying out aggressive acts outside the territory of Russia without declaring war?** (ie acts which would normally be prohibited by the constitution inside Russia)

Significance: The armed forces of the Russian Federation take an oath to uphold the constitution. It would seem that under that oath, they not only can but **must** disobey orders that are against the constitution. Russian troops have in many cases already avoided deployment on a number of flimsy technicalities; if literally everything about the war is unconstitutional that would open room for a lot more of the same.

Comment: Is there any point in trying to find it out? I think you can be 100% sure that if you ask this question the [Constitutional Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_Court_of_Russia) it will answer "no". And that will be the only one [technically] legally correct answer, however many independent experts would think it is not.

Comment: @Greendrake Yes, I think there is, at least two good reasons:

1. It allows people to refuse illegal orders. There have been really dumb reasons that people have used successfully, like "we can't go abroad without passports" (really - that worked). More reasons like that would be good - especially if they undermine the very basis for the war.

2. After the war (and presumably with new courts) all of these crimes can be tried as crimes under the old domestic laws - it wouldn't even require an international court, or new (retroactive) laws.

Comment: @Esee flaw in your logic there: if the CC determines that it is all legally correct, then the orders are not illegal and it is the refusal of legitimate orders.

Comment: @Trish The point is to resist this by any means possible. Even if the case loses in court - how long does it take? How many individual cases like that would there be? You're also missing the potentially huge value of even having a case like this filed: it establishes that it is *arguably possible* that the war and/or the way it is conducted is unconstitutional. Also of course in Russia this is not a "war" (even illegal to call it that), and refusing orders in "peacetime" just leads to discharge, nothing more serious than that (also been done).

Comment: @Trish Also (if my reading is correct) Ukrainian civilians can sue the Russian government and probably also individual officials. Russia is repressive but it is also very much about rules and procedures, and while you may think they can arbitrarily dismiss stuff like this - in fact it creates a huge problem because they have to figure out how to dismiss it under their existing rules, and also keep it quiet. So please please don't tell me reasons why it's pointless and just try to answer the question at hand.